# Lebesgue integral of $f : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$, where $f$ is defined as a piecewise function.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Today during my measure theory lecture, my professor introduced the following problem to us

> Suppose that $f: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ is defined by letting $f(x)=0$ on the Cantor set $\mathcal{C}$ and $f(x) =k$ for all $x$ in each interval of length $3^{-k}$ which has been removed from $[0,1]$. Calculate $\int^{1}_0fdm$ (the Lebesgue integral of $f$).

I am trying to rework this problem since we did it during lecture, however, I have a few questions about my professors work:

He stated that given how $f$ is defined in the problem, we can deduce that $$f(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k2^{k-1}\chi_{A_{k}}(x) \label{a}\tag{1}$$ where $\chi_{A_{k}}$ is the indicator function of $A_k$, the union of $2^{k-1}$ intervals of length $3^{-k}$ each, that are removed from $[0,1]$ at the $k^{th}$ stage.

I actually understand every step from here on out, but I am not understanding how he went from how $f$ is given in the problem to $(1)$. I have been doing some serious digging and considered that this utilizes the Cantor-Lebesgue function? If someone could point me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated.

---

$p.s.$ I couldn't fit the question in title here, so if someone has a better title for this post $-$ please do edit.

Comment: (1) is not correct. $2^{k-1}$ should not be there on RHS.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy - Thats what I thought too but I wanted to check here before emailing him. Shouldn't it just be $k\chi_{A_{k}}(x)$?

Comment: @TaylorRendon Yes,  that is right.